# Булевые знаечния и логически операции

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста как это работате?

```js
do {
  var name = prompt("Who are you?");
  console.log(Boolean(name));
  } while (!name);
  console.log(name);
```

Comment: пока вы не введете любое значение у вас будет выводится `false` иначе выведется `true` и значение которое вы ввели

Comment: Что именно вы не поняли? Что такое `do-while`, или `!name`, или `prompt`, или `Boolean(name)`, или что?

Comment: Если я не ввожу ничего в prompt, то name становиться false, дальше идет в while ( !name), мне здесь не понятно. Ведь ! - это логическое отрицание, тогда name, которая false, становиться true и код сonsole.log должен выполняться, а получатеся все наоборот.